# @Autowired does not set field --> NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, nullpointerexception

I want to integrate Struts 2, Hibernate and Spring. I made a previous example project with Hibernate, Spring, Spring MVC. And it worked fine. Now I want to replace Spring MVC with Struts 2. And I have following problem. I have LoginAction class with field `@Autowired private UserService userService`. UserService class contains as a field UserDAO field that also annotated as Autowired. UserDAO contains SessionFactory that annotated too. I'm sure that struts confiration is right. And applicationContext.xml also right. Because when I make some changes in this file, I got an exceptions. Tomcat starts without errors and shows me login page. But when I tried to call methods of UserService class, I got a NPE, because this object is null. Why Spring did not set this object? My code:
applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

<bean id="userDAO" class="com.example.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO" />
<bean id="userService" class="com.example.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/database" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="user" />
</bean>
<bean name="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.entity.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
      </param-value>
</context-param> 
</web-app>
```

LoginAction class:

```
@Controller
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
private String login;
private String password;
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    User user = null;
    try {
        user = userService.findByLogin(login);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (user != null) {
        return user.getPassword().equals(password) ? SUCCESS : ERROR;
    }
    return ERROR;
}
// getters and setters
}
```

UserService implementation class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public User findByLogin(String login) throws SQLException {
    return userDAO.findByLogin(login);
} }
```

And UserDAO impl class:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateUserDAO implements UserDAO {
@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Override
public User findByLogin(String login) throws SQLException {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("login", login)).list().get(0);
} }
```

Struts confiration is fine, because it react correctly. Why Spring did not set fields? Any ideas?

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="com.example.web.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/cabinet.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Did you use the spring struts integration dependancies in your application? looks like it does not work straight out of the box by replacing the spring mvc layer with that of the struts.

Comment: Post `struts.xml` file.

Comment: Did you put the struts-spring plugin to your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @SotiriosDelimanolis said, you are `mixing` things. Here is you do:

1. remove @Controller annotaion from your controller classes.
2. check if you have already `struts2-spring-plugin` in your classpath. `NOTE:` The version of the plugin should be as same as your strut2 version.
3. make should you have defined your spring beans in `application-context.xml`, whatever explicit or over component-scan.
4. check if there is

   ```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>
             org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```

   defined in your `web.xml`

have fun! Here is the `link` of the [REFERENCE](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/spring-plugin.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing things. Spring will create a context because you've declared a `ContextLoaderListener`, but `Struts` will create its own stack of `Action` (`ActionSupport`) classes from your struts.xml configuration file. In other words, it's instantiating its own `LoginAction` object.

Comment: You cannot be sure in that w/o seeing `struts.xml` first.

Comment: @AleksandrM Sure of what? I can be sure that the `struts.xml` can't be referring to beans inside the Spring `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Struts2 knows how to instantiate the action due its container, but delegates to spring `BeanFactory` because spring plugin modifies `struts.ObjectFactory` setting.

Comment: @RomanC I will delete my answer id OP shows evidence of this configuration.

Comment: so, I need to not use Spring listener in web.xml?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think OP's problems are far enough from struts-spring integration, if he won't show the evidence of beans creation.

Comment: @OleksandrHubachov Start by showing us your `struts` configuration.

Comment: @OleksandrHubachov With that configuration, `struts` creates its own `LoginAction` instance which it uses. That instance has no relation to the Spring bean instance.

Comment: @RomanC I don't think there is such spring plugin in this context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, so how to solve this problem? just remove spring listener and use struts-spring plugin in pom.xml? or something else?

Comment: @OleksandrHubachov I can't help you with that. I don't know enough about struts-spring integration.

Comment: Leave the Spring listener (that's what bootstraps Spring), but add the struts2-spring-plugin, which will cause Struts to use Spring for creating actions and other objects (interceptors, results, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using spring MVC (by not using dispatcher servlet in web.xml); yet you are trying to use MVC api annotations like @Controller in the Action servlet. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: I just want to replace Spring MVC with Struts2. And I try to do this

Comment: Try to use <code>@Component</code> instead of <code>@Controller</code> and check if it resolves that. But I highly doubt it.

Comment: `@Controller` isn't a Spring MVC annotation, it's a Spring annotation. The fact that Spring MVC happens to use it is irrelevant. He does need to declare his actions as prototype scoped, though.